# Does CvSVM scale the training data?

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I am using OpenCV's CvSVM to learn SVM classifiers for 29 Classes.

The application is Face Recognition, and I divide the face image into 3x6 grid. For each block in the grid, I train a SVM classifier on the SURF features extracted from the block.

I read here http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks.html that it is very important to scale the training and testing data similarly.

Does CvSVM scale the data? If not, does OpenCV provide any function I can use to do the scaling?

Comment: `CvSVM` does not automatically scale data. Depending upon what type of normalisation you want to do, OpenCV will almost certainly have optimised routines to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

there's a very good cross-platform library for utilizing machine learning algorithms in practice: 
http://www.nickgillian.com/software/grt

I don't know whether OpenCV provides opportunity for scaling training/test data to achieve a better classification result, but with GRT you can do it:
https://github.com/nickgillian/grt/blob/master/GRT/ClassificationModules/SVM/SVM.h

```
...
@param bool useScaling: sets if the training/prediction data will be scaled to the default range of [-1. 1.]. The SVM algorithm commonly achieves a better classification result if scaling is turned on. The default useScaling value is useScaling=true
...
SVM(UINT kernelType = LINEAR_KERNEL,UINT svmType = C_SVC,bool useScaling = true,bool useNullRejection = false,bool useAutoGamma = true,double gamma = 0.1,UINT degree = 3,double coef0 = 0,double nu = 0.5,double C = 1,bool useCrossValidation = false,UINT kFoldValue = 10);
```

This is also a wrapper class to libsvm.